# Sinatra and mysql2 gem raw mysql queries errors

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, mysql2

Using:

- ruby 1.8.7
- sinatra (1.4.5)
- mysql2 (0.3.16)
- raw mysql queries

I have 2-3 queries (they arent too heavy, medium or simple) separately on one page, and when I open this page f.e. 10 times. I have 4 different mysql2 gem error dynamicly (not all at once):

```
Mysql2::Error - closed MySQL connection:

Mysql2::Error - MySQL server has gone away:

Mysql2::Error - Malformed packet

Mysql2::Error - Lost connection to MySQL server during
```

Already tried to use:

```
:reconnect => true
```

And still nothing

Any suggestions ?
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like some information might be missing here... the error messages suggest that there is a connectivity problem. Can you connect to the MySQL server manually from the same machine, using the same credentials? Is that connection stable? Maybe if you show us your code, we might get more relevant information

Comment: DB is on local machine and I can connect manually.

Comment: And one more question, I need to get connection before each request or I connection is persistent ?